# How to use formula in custom button defination

Tags: apex, formula, custom-button

In below custom button defination I want to use RIGHT and FIND function in 4th line, how can I use, please suggest

```
/006/e? 
&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id} 
&accid={!Case.AccountId} 
&opp3=OP-RIGHT({!Case.CaseNumber},FIND("-", {!Case.CaseNumber},1)-1)} 
&opp9={! DATEVALUE( Case.CreatedDate ) +45} 
&00N90000004Muo1=SRV - Service 
&opp11=Proposal/Price Quote
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to move the RIGHT function inside the expressions syntax {!}

```
/006/e? 
&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id} 
&accid={!Case.AccountId} 
&opp3=OP-{!RIGHT(Case.CaseNumber,FIND("-", {!Case.CaseNumber},1)-1)} 
&opp9={! DATEVALUE( Case.CreatedDate ) +45} 
&00N90000004Muo1=SRV - Service 
&opp11=Proposal/Price Quote
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Krishna, Now I have 1 more problem I'm unable to use this custom button at my visualforce page using following line of code <apex:commandButton Value="New Opprotunity" action="{!urlfor($Action.Case.NewOpportunity,Case.id)}"/>.  Button is working fine at standard page. Pl help